# How to pass the select value to database using ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my html code. I want to insert the option value to database using ajax. Please help

```
if($row['showComment']=='S'){
        echo "<td><select class='col-md-6 form-control form-control-lg combSelect' id='scmnt' name='setcombo1'><option>Select</option><option value='S' selected>Show</option><option value='H'>Hide</option><option value='P'>Pending</option></select></td>";}
elseif ($row['showComment']=='H') {
                                echo "<td><select class='col-md-6 form-control form-control-lg combSelect' name='setcombo1'><option>Select</option><option value='S' >Show</option><option value='H' selected>Hide</option><option value='P'>Pending</option></select></td>";}
elseif ($row['showComment']=='P') {
                                 echo "<td><select class='col-md-6 form-control form-control-lg combSelect' name='setcombo1'><option>Select</option><option value='S' >Show</option><option value='H'>Hide</option><option value='P' selected>Pending</option></select></td>";}
else{
     echo "<td><select class='col-md-6 form-control form-control-lg combSelect' name='setcombo1'><option selected>Select</option><option value='S' >Show</option><option value='H'>Hide</option><option value='P'>Pending</option></select></td>";}
```

This is my ajax script

```
$('.combSelect').on('change', function(){
  var donor_id = this.value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:'donor_id='+donor_id,
    url: "addComment.php"
  });
});
```

Comment: where is your Javascript? Have you attempted this ye?

Comment: Yes is attempt this but not working

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then ajax file

```
    <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname)
VALUES ('$q')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```